# PAGINAÇÃO SPRING em API MOCK

Tags: java, api, spring, jpa, paginação

estou fazendo uma API em Java, e implementei a paginação, o resultado da paginação em JSON é o seguinte:

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      (AQUI TEM OS RESULTADOS DA QUERY)
    }
  ],
  "empty": true,
  "first": true,
  "last": true,
  "number": 0,
  "numberOfElements": 0,
  "pageable": {
    "offset": 0,
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 0,
    "paged": true,
    "sort": {
      "empty": true,
      "sorted": true,
      "unsorted": true
    },
    "unpaged": true
  },
  "size": 0,
  "sort": {
    "empty": true,
    "sorted": true,
    "unsorted": true
  },
  "totalElements": 0,
  "totalPages": 0
}
```

Tambem tenho uma outra classe chamada "BaseRetorno" que tem os mesmos itens que a paginação, porem em português:

```
{
  "itens": [
    {
      (AQUI ERA PARA VIR O RESULTADO DA CONSULTA)
    }
  ],
  "paginacao": {
    "pagina": 0,
    "tamanhoPagina": 0,
    "totalPaginas": 0,
    "totalItens": 0
  }
}
```

Basicamente, eu gostaria de fazer a paginação pela minha classe, para que fosse exibido em português, eu não consegui renomear e nem modificar os valores do "content" nem dos outros atributos da paginação do Spring. Alguém pode me ajudar com isso, como eu poderia fazer que minha classe agisse igual, ou pegasse os valores da paginação? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi direito o que você quer.

Primeiro ponto, não seria uma boa pratica você utilizar uma classe de pagina própria, recomendo que use a pagina fornecida pelo Spring.

Segundo ponto, como você não disponibilizou as classes do seu projeto eu vou presumir que esteja seguindo as praticas comuns do Spring, e para o exemplo usarei uma classe minha.

primeiro você vai precisar de uma classe que guarde as informações da paginação.

```
public class Paginacao {

    private int pagina;
    private int tamanhoPagina;
    private int totalPaginas;
    private long totalItens;

    public Paginacao(int pagina, int tamanhoPagina, int totalPaginas, long totalItens) {
        this.pagina = pagina;
        this.tamanhoPagina = tamanhoPagina;
        this.totalPaginas = totalPaginas;
        this.totalItens = totalItens;
    }
//getter, setter e contrutor sem args.
}
```

Repare que há um construtor com parâmetros.

agora vamos criar a classe que de fato será a pagina

```
public class PaginaEmPortugues {

private List<Book> itens;
private Paginacao paginacao;

public PaginaEmPortugues(Page<Book> page) {
    this.itens = page.getContent();
    this.paginacao = new Paginacao(
            page.getPageable().getPageNumber(),
            page.getPageable().getPageSize(),
            page.getTotalPages(),
            page.getTotalElements()
    );
//getter, setter e contrutor sem args.
}
```

Repare que usamos o construtor da classe anterior no construtor dessa classe.

e por fim o método no controller:

```
@GetMapping
private PaginaEmPortugues readAll(@PageableDefault(sort="nome", direction = Sort.Direction.ASC, page = 0, size = 20) Pageable pageable){

    Page<Book> englishPage = bookRepository.findAll(pageable);
    return new PaginaEmPortugues(englishPage);
}
```

Espero que entenda meu código, outro ponto, é que caso queira utilizar essa pagina para varias classe diferentes, você deve dar uma pesquisada sobre generics e então implementar nessa classe.

Para provar que funcionar eu testei.

```
{
"itens": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "nome": "Descrição"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Descrição"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nome": "Descrição"
    }
],
"paginacao": {
    "pagina": 0,
    "tamanhoPagina": 20,
    "totalPaginas": 1,
    "totalItens": 3
}
```

}